# Terminology: zero-knowledge forecasting vs some-knowledge forecasting?

Tags: forecasting, terminology

Suppose you're doing time series forecasting where you have no knowledge what the dominant seasonality is likely to be, and you don't know other characteristics of the data that help you choose appropriate algorithms and configure them suitably. Perhaps you only have a small amount of historical data to infer from, or perhaps you expect that the seasonality and other characteristics of the data may change over time as new measurements become available.

**Is there a word or phrase that's commonly used to refer to this type of forecasting scenario?** And is there a word or phrase for the more typical scenario where you do have more knowledge?

If it helps to clarify, in my particular situation I'm using "meta-algorithms" that automatically choose the best algorithm or choose the optimal configuration parameters, such as R's `auto.arima`, `ets`, and `stlf`. I'm periodically re-running these algorithms to see if the characteristics of the data have changed.

**Alternatively, can you refer me to any papers or books that discuss this scenario?** It's difficult to search for something when you don't know what it's called. Surely I am not the only person to have faced this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call the case where forecasting uses less historical data and more intuition to be **Bayesian forecasting**:

> Bayesian forecasting is a natural product of a Bayesian approach to inference. The Bayesian approach in general requires explicit formulation of a model, and conditioning on known quantities, in order to draw inferences about unknown ones.

Source: [Bayesian Forecasting by J Geweke and C Whiteman](https://notendur.hi.is/bge1/bayesian_forecasting.pdf)

The other case, using historical data alone to forecast, doesn't have a differentiating name that i am aware of.